# SQLite3 Unsupported datatype

Tags: python-3.x, base-de-datos, sqlite3, scraping, sqldatatypes

Resulta que estoy haciendo scraping en una pagina para hacer un mini proyecto. Quiero que los resultados se guarden en una base de datos SQLite3. Mi problema es que la base de datos me rechaza cualquier tipo de dato con el que intento pasarle las variables. Adjunto parte del codigo:

```
# Eliminación de espacio blanco y filtrado de datos sobre las variables que hemos conseguido con el anterior paso

confCasesSpain_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(confCasesSpain))
confCasesEurope_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(confCasesEurope))
confCasesWorldWide_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(confCasesWorldWide))
vacunasDistribuidas_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(vacunasDistribuidas))
vacunasAdministradas_Numero  = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(vacunasAdministradas))
vacunasCompletas_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(vacunasCompletas))


# Printeo de variables por la consola

print("Casos confirmados en España: ", confCasesSpain_Numero)
print("Casos confirmados en Europa: ", confCasesEurope_Numero)
print("Casos confirmados en el Mundo: ", confCasesWorldWide_Numero)
print("Vacunas distribuidas en España: ", vacunasDistribuidas_Numero)
print("De las cuales administradas: ", vacunasAdministradas_Numero)
print("De las cuales son completas: ", vacunasCompletas_Numero)
```

El codigo de arriba da este output:

```
Casos confirmados en España:  ['3.514.942']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Casos confirmados en Europa:  ['49.979.244']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Casos confirmados en el Mundo:  ['148.329.348']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Vacunas distribuidas en España:  ['17.465.205']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
De las cuales administradas:  ['15.859.772']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
De las cuales son completas:  ['4.413.784']
```

Yo intento guardar las variables de la siguiente forma:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('BaseDePrueba.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Covid19 ("Fecha" TEXT, "Casos confirmados España" REAL, "Casos confirmados Europa" TEXT, "Casos confirmados mundialmente" TEXT, "Vacunas distribuidas" TEXT, "Vacunas Administradas" TEXT, "Vacunas Completas" TEXT)''')

def data_entry():
    hoy = date.today()
    dia = hoy.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Covid19 ('Fecha','Casos confirmados España') VALUES (?, ?)", (dia, confCasesSpain_Numero))
    conn.commit()

create_table()
data_entry()
```

He probado con **REAL, INTEGER, TEXT y BLOB** y todos dan el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
File "scrapperpython2.0 - copia.py", line 86, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
data_entry()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
File "scrapperpython2.0 - copia.py", line 82, in data_entry                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
c.execute("INSERT INTO Covid19 ('Fecha','Casos confirmados España') VALUES (?, ?)", (dia, 
confCasesSpain_Numero))                                                                                                                                                                                                        
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

No entiendo como guardar estas variables, alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que el problema eran los [''].
Lo resolví buscando en el mismo foro como deshacerse de estos simbolos, y fue tan sencillo como añadir **[0]** al final de las siguientes líneas:

```
confCasesSpain_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(confCasesSpain))[0]
confCasesEurope_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(confCasesEurope))[0]
confCasesWorldWide_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(confCasesWorldWide))[0]
vacunasDistribuidas_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(vacunasDistribuidas))[0]
vacunasAdministradas_Numero  = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(vacunasAdministradas))[0]
vacunasCompletas_Numero = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+', str(vacunasCompletas))[0]
```